# Probability of no birthdays for X consecutive days within a group of n people

Tags: probability, birthday

Consider a group of `n` people. Assume 365 days in a year and that birthdays are independent and uniformly distributed.

What is the probably that `n` people have no birthdays for `X` consecutive days?

For example, what is the probability that 31 people have no birthdays for 31 consecutive days?

Comment: Let $T$ denote the probability that one person does not have a birthday in the next $31$ days, including today.  Then, you want $~\displaystyle T^{(31)}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting only because I think that the other posted answer is wrong.  For $1$ specific person, the event of not having a birthday on January 1 (for example) is **not independent** of that person not having a birthday on January 2.

For one specific person, the probability that the person will not have a birthday in the next $X$ days, including today is

$$T = \frac{365 - X}{365}.$$

Therefore, the probability that none of $n$ people have a birthday in the next $X$ days (including today) is

$$T^n.$$